# NERDTree - Extra space between folder icons and arrows

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am noticing an extra space between the NERTree folder icons and the arrows. Below is the screenshot of the same.

[image]

So how can I remove this ? I am using `ryanoasis/vim-devicons` plugin and using this setting `let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1` to display the folder icon.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the folder icon is a *double-width character*, whereas the others are *single width*. If you yank the corresponding character into the default register, you can check with

```
:echo strdisplaywidth(@@)
```

The solution then would be to consistently configure one or the other character width, but no mixture. (Or include padding spaces in the single-width ones, if that's possible.)

In the [vim devicons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) add-on plugin that you're using, [there's a way to change individual icons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/wiki/Extra-Configuration#character-mappings). You also might want to raise an issue there to alert the author about this aesthetic inconsistency; maybe there's another way to fix it (or maybe this is just about your local font and not a general issue after all).

Comment: Sorry but how can i fix it then ?

Comment: Where do these icons come from? I also have NERDTree (latest on master), but none of these icons. I also don't see them on the plugin's GitHub page.

Comment: I am using `ryanoasis/vim-devicons` plugin and using this setting `let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1`

Comment: Ah well, you should have mentioned that in your question! Apparently, [there's a way to change individual icons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/wiki/Extra-Configuration#character-mappings). You also might want to raise an issue there to alert the author about this aesthetic inconsistency; maybe there's another way to fix it (or maybe this is just about your local font and not a general issue after all).

Comment: Just updated the question, also I had already tried setting a different folder icon but it didn't help and I am using `Inconsolata` from `nderfonts.com`.

Comment: So, have you actually checked the icon width (as per my answer), and then chosen a single-cell icon as a replacement? I mean, I was just guessing; it could very well be a different problem.

Comment: Yeah.. I did check and you were spot on i mean the icon width is 2.

Comment: Ah, so the fix should be clear: You need to consistently use one width: either all one-cell, al two-cell, or pad the one-celled ones with another space, so that they are also two cells wide. As the icons seem to be stored in a certain structure, you could even use metaprogramming for the padding to avoid the long and repetitive definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188430/discussion-between-rohit-and-ingo-karkat).